# SSL certificate expire | error in Plesk

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, web-hosting, plesk

A customer tries to Connect to abc.xyz.com on the command line.

Try to connect to abc.xyz.com server, by making a request from the command line with internal IP (as a previously raised issue on accessing with the domain name is still not working we are requesting with internal IP.) This was working fine till yesterday with SSL like

```
wget https://0.0.0.0(IP)/en/report/json/2017/home
```

But now it's giving below error!

```
[root@Server ~]# wget https://0.0.0.0/IP/en/report/json/2017/home
--2018-05-13 13:06:42--  https://0.0.0.0/IP/en/report/json/2017/home Connecting to 0.0.0.0/IP:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify 0.0.0.0/IP's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2’: Issued certificate has expired.
ERROR: certificate common name **‘*.xyz.com’** doesn't match requested host name ‘0.0.0.0/IP’. To connect to 0.0.0.0/IP insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Now, things to notice is the certificate issued to "*.xyz.com", is located on the load balancer.

Server locally (via command line) can't send the request to load balancer. 
Which means it's checking it locally and gating a certificate that is either expire or not machining to the host.

The domain name abc.xyz.com can't be resolved by IP so the customer has to use the domain name.

So I suggested customer to upload their SSL certificate to Plesk web portal by user webmaster in order to resolve this SSL certificate error and use the domain name instead of IP, what you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes. Uploading the certificate to Plesk and accessing a website via domain name will surely resolve the error.

The other logical way of addressing this error is to skip certificate checks:

```
# wget --no-check-certificate https://0.0.0.0(IP)/en/report/json/2017/home
```

Since the client and the a website are located on the same server, there is no much point of worrying about data interception (while the default website for the IP address is not changed).

Comment: Well at first I tried that only but you know...client’s